# Creating full-height vertical menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I force my tabs to take all the remaining space in the vertical menu? so, adjust the spaces between the tabs according to the number of tabs.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="lien_menu"><br>Onglet0 loooooooog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="lien_menu"><br>Onglet1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my current code : http://jsfiddle.net/96EGh/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question... By 'tabs' do you mean the `li` elements? If so, you are talking about the space between `li` elements, which is vertical space, but the question title says "full-width" suggesting horizontal space

Comment: Yes, my title is wrong, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the fill the width or the height?

If you mean the height (as it's a vertical menu). You need to give your container a height so that the UL will fill it, and allow the LI elements to fill the rest of the space.

I've made a fiddle using a fixed height and `display: table;` / `display: table-cell;` to achieve this at http://jsfiddle.net/96EGh/3/

You can add more LI elements and they will fill the space.

Answer (score 1):

you can do by css

```
ul{display:table;}
ul li{display:table-cell;}
```

Comment: You could put more effort into your answer. Explain why... for example

Answer (score 0):

You can do percentages.

```
ul li {width:48%;margin-right:1%;}
ul{width:100%}
```

Comment: Your solution is not flexible, re-read the question **"adjust the spaces between the tabs according to the number of tabs."**. What if there are three tabs?

Comment: Than you give each tab 33% width... You are not sharp with math?

Comment: So what if there are 4, 5, 6. 8...he has to update his CSS every time? Do you need to look up the word "flexible"?

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages in width and Ems in font.

Comment: Don't let paulie D see this. He is going to give you a negative comment and down vote, even though he has not made any suggestions himself.

Comment: @httpgio He was rather condescending, but your solution is not correct, and downvoting an incorrect solution is not contingent on him knowing the correct solution.